# Sql Server 2008 With Array

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in my sql:

Users :

```
id    name     roleid
1     David    1
2     Sean     2
3     Joe      1
```

Roles:

```
roleid    desc
1         copy
2         delete
3         move
```

Now i use this cmd to select the user with the user permission

```
SELECT * FROM Users u INNER JOIN Roles r ON u.roleid = r.roleid
```

Now i want to know if it's possible to build SQL Table(Roles Table), that it's will be dynamically the number of roleid for each user. something like:

Users :

```
id    name     roleid roleid2 roleid3
1     David    1      2       3
2     Sean     2   
3     Joe      1      3
```

Comment: How about using a View? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: View is something like a dynamically table?

Comment: It can be used as a virtual table yes and it states in the documentation: "Join columns from multiple tables so that they look like a single table." That seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: But i don't understand how i can use it to build a table like users with dynamically roleid columns

Comment: I don't see where this data currently lives. Is each user listed more than once in the users table if they have more than one role, or is there another table (UserRoles) that you didn't share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to address the many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Roles`. A composite primary key in the `UserRole` table will prevent duplicate assignment of roles, and foreign keys referencing the `Users` and `Roles` table will preserve referential integrity.

See [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db702/4) for a sample implementation.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I suggest you to use many to many relationship. It means trird table: UsersRoles (userid,roleid)
At second, it's impossible create dynamic number of columns in typical SQL statement. But its possible by using stored procedures.

here is working example
[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/311fc/2)